# jQuery event handlers closures vs contexts

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Looking at the following jQuery's code:

```
$button.on("click", {context: "externalRef1"}, function(e){ if (e.data.context){...}  });
```

I wonder when should I pass data into the handler as context (as per the above sample) and why can't I always rely on closures (nevermind conflicting names - it isn't an issue really)?

Some clarifications - closures are about allowing to the code to use external vars, i.e.

```
var foo = function(){

    var externalRef = "a1";

    var call = function(){}{
       alert(externalRef); // a1
    }    
};
```

if that's always the case why do you need to pass data the way pointed up above?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... Where is this code from? We need some background on *why* you're using this `context` value?

Comment: I use an external value cos I need get access to something from a different scope other than the event handler.

Comment: Different situations call for different techniques. The closure variables will only be directly accessible to the functions that were in that scope, while the object you provided as event data can be passed around and shared freely. Use what makes sense at each given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of taste, actually. For me, closures are a more explicit and "natural" way to pass data around. However in some situations `event.data` is simply more convenient, in loops for example:

```
// doesn't do what you want!
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    $("#button" + i).on("click", function(e) { alert("Button " + i + " clicked") });

// works just fine
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    $("#button" + i).on("click", {i: i}, function(e) { alert("Button " + e.data.i + " clicked") });
```

Another use case is a single function acting as an event handler for multiple objects:

```
$("#add_button").on("click", {action: "+"}, calculatorButtonClicked);
$("#mul_button").on("click", {action: "*"}, calculatorButtonClicked);
$("#div_button").on("click", {action: "/"}, calculatorButtonClicked);

function calculatorButtonClicked(e) {

    ...lots of common code

    switch(e.data.action) {
        case '+': result = x + y;
        case '*': result = x * y;
            etc
    }

    ...lots of common code

}
```

Comment: Loops are the dealbreaker indeed...

Comment: Can you clone a value in JS - that would in theory fix the problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user1514042: To make a copy of the value for each iteration is what you use a closure for.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use closures, or always context, or always some other solution, or pick any solution for any situation. Neither is wrong.

You can use the one that fits best for each situation, or the one that you are most confident with.

Comment: I actually came across with a case when closures don't work, I'm looking for a generalized reason for it. In brief a closure won't work with the variable passed as a parameter into a higher scope and then cached.

Comment: @user1514042: I can't see a reason why a closure wouldn't work for that. If you are talking about the example that thg435 is showing, the closure isn't working because there is no closure at all. If you actually use a close, it works just fine.